# Error while downloading platform specific binaries for hyperledger fabric in

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install hyperleger fabric in UBUNTU 18.04 TS.. following this [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html)

My specifications are

```
OS        UBUNTU 18.04 TS
curl      7.58.0
Docker    19.03.6  
nodejs    8.10.0
npm       5.6.0
python   2.7.17
git version   2.17.1
```

When I get to the part of installing the binaries and docker images using  `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh`. I tried with a shortend link as shown in this image [shortened link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7GuF.png)

The fabric samples get installed but the binaries that include the bin and config files are not installed. I have tried including version identifiers to download specific versions. I'm getting error

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: child return status 1
tar:  error is not recoverable: exiting now
===> there was an error downloading binary file.
```

See this image for more information [terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atvbb.png). [shortened link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2DVL.png) and still end up with the same issue.

Can someone help me solve this? Thanks in advance..

ps. this is my first time in stack overflow and I'm unable to post the shortened url and have included them as shortened links..

**edit**

I tried to extract the bin and config folders by downloading the specific binary versions from github under assets as mentioned below by one of the users(I downloade the 1.4.8 version)..

But when I try to bring up the network from first-network dotrectory it throws up the following error..
[image: terminal output 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute the un-shortened URL with this command:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/release-2.2/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s
```

After bash -s, you can put your version specific parameters, like

```
bash -s -- <fabric_version> <fabric-ca_version>
```

So for fabric version 2.2.0 and fabric-ca-version 1.4.8:

```
bash -s -- 2.2.0 1.4.8
```

So the un-shorted URL will be

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/release-2.2/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 2.2.0 1.4.8
```

Link of the source:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#

Comment: Thank you so much.. It didn't work in the first try, but I tweaked the version specifc parameers and was able to download it..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems trying to use the provided bootstrap script. For me it made sense in some cases to check the page directly https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases to understand:

- whether the version I try to download exists
- whether the link built by the script is correct

From this page you can download the binaries directly per click, you find them under assets[image: Screenshot].

Comment: I cloned the fabric-samples directory, downloaded the 1.4.8 linux version and extracted the 'bin' and 'config' folder into the fabric-samples. But when i try to bring up the network it throws up another error

Comment: I've posted it in the question can u please refer that

Comment: Seems like there is some kind of mismatch between the architectures (for which the binaries were compiled and where they are used). Is you linux distribution 32 or 64 bit?